# Selenium hangs when starting new remoteWebDriver session using Microsoft Edge web browser on Windows 10 VM

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

We are getting an error when starting a session of the remote web driver for Microsoft Edge on a Windows 10 VM.
We have a selenium grid configured with multiple nodes that have various OS/browser combinations.  All nodes with the exception of our new Windows 10 node are working as expected.  We have configured a Windows 10 VM with the Microsoft Edge browser `version=21.10586.0.0` and added the `MicrosoftWebDriver` on the VM. The path to the web driver on the VM is set with the system property -

```
-Dwebdriver.edge.driver="C:\Selenium\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"
```

In my selenium test I instantiate the selenium web driver that is configured to the `MicrosoftWebDriver` on the Windows 10 VM.  During the initialization I set the capabilities for the remote driver and I have log output that is set:

```
08:57:32.932 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, applicationName=Win10_EDGE, version=21.10586.0.0}]])
08:57:32.948 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, applicationName=Win10_EDGE, version=21.10586.0.0}]
```

The remote connection is established, the Edge browser is opened on the VM and is operational.  At that point the code hangs creating the remote driver in the selenium code - selenium-remote-driver-2.53.0.jar

Eventually it times out with the error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:124)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:79)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:204)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:166)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:132)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:113)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:97)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timeout (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 917.04 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
        at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:152)
        at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:120)
        ... 14 more
13:28:49.532 WARN - Exception: Timeout (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 917.04 seconds
```

I am using:
selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar, 
Microsoft WebDriver Fall 2015 Update from the Microsoft site

I noticed that the System info above lists Windows 8 - even though Windows 10 is installed.

Has anyone else seen this issue or have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to run a script locally on the VM? Have you also tried with the edge driver v14271 ? It looks like the browser is not responding to the driver. I would also check that the connection is not blocked by the firewall.

Comment: Thanks, I will try both.

Comment: I tried running a script locally on the VM and it worked!  Thanks for the advice.  Does this mean that it's an issue with the Selenium RemoteWebDriver if it's not a firewall issue?

Answer (score 0):

During my successful yet painful struggle to set up Edge as a part of a Selenium grid I was getting very similar Exceptions. There are at least 2 possible problems here:

1. Is selenium-standalone-server started in the background (for example using Task-Scheduler) or foreground? (for example manually or as a startup program)
   Edge driver must be running in the foreground, so that its window can be actually displayed on the desktop. Therefore the node cannot be started as a Windows Service nor from Windows Task Scheduler at startup. The best way to automate starting of the node is to configure auto-login and add a batch script starting the node to user's Startup Programs as described in [my article](http://morgwai.pl/articles/selenium-edge.html).
2. Are there other browsers enabled in the same node as Edge? This is known to cause problems. It is recommended to start 2 separate nodes on the same machine (on different ports of course) : one only for Edge and second for IE, FF and Chrome. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387991/setting-up-selenium-grid-to-use-microsoft-edge/45621125#45621125) for more info.