# Setting up selenium grid to use Microsoft edge

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, vaadin, microsoft-edge

**Environment:**

- win10 (build 10240)
- Vaadin Testbench 4.1
- Selenium 2.53
- Drivers for Firefox, Chrome, IE11 and Edge for build 10240

**Node and hub**

start java -jar c:\users\powder\vaadin-testbench-standalone-4.1.0.jar -role hub
start java -jar c:\users\powder\vaadin-testbench-standalone-4.1.0.jar -role node -Dwebdriver.edge.driver=c:\users\powder\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe

**Usage in java code**

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setBrowserName(DesiredCapabilities.edge().getBrowserName());
//DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.edge(); Tried as well
capabilities.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", "true");
setDriver(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(this.remoteHubUrl), capabilities));
getDriver().get("http://www.google.com");
```

**Errormessage**

> Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=MicrosoftEdge}]

[Selenium grid console - edge is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzbnC.png)

Everything is working fine with other browsers, but not with Edge. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 problems here:

First, if you look at [the default node config](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.4.0/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultNodeWebDriver.json) you will notice that only Firefox, Chrome and IE are enabled by default (that's why all you need to use them is specify driver location via a system property). If you want to use any other browser then you need to use your own json config:

```
{
  "capabilities": [
    {
      "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
      "platform": "WIN10",
      "maxInstances": 1
    },
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "platform": "WIN10",
      "maxInstances": 5
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "platform": "WIN10",
      "maxInstances": 5
    },
    {
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "platform": "WIN10",
      "maxInstances": 1
    }
  ],
  "hub": "http://selenium-hub-host:4444"
}
```

and pass it to your command line:

`java "-Dwebdriver.edge.driver=c:\path\to\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" "-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=c:\path\to\geckodriver.exe" "-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\path\to\chromedriver.exe" "-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=c:\path\to\IEDriverServer.exe" -jar "c:\path\to\selenium-server-standalone.jar" -role node -nodeConfig "c:\path\to\the\above.json"`

(btw: alternatively you can also put the whole config in your command line using multiple `-capabilities` or `-browser` params)

This in theory should work. However in practice you will often be hit by the 2nd problem, which is: "sometimes it randomly doesn't work" ;] Initially everything will look fine: your grid will properly report Edge browser capability on the console, it will properly delegate tests to a node containing Edge, the node will properly start Edge browser, however the browser will sometimes freeze on its initial blue screen with e logo and after few seconds you will get some exception on the client side without any meaningful stack-trace nor message (I don't have it saved anywhere to paste here now).

Some people suggested a [workaround](https://www.ranorex.com/forum/get-edge-to-show-up-in-selenium-grid-t11075.html) to start 2 separate nodes on the same machine (on different ports of course) : one only for Edge and second for IE, FF and Chrome. This way it seems to work pretty stable (tested on Edge build 15063 running on win-10 and Selenium-3.4.0)

**Additional info:**

Apart from the above, Edge driver has few limitations that require specific workarounds in the configuration:

- currently only 1 concurrent session is supported by the driver/browser so `maxInstances` must be set to 1 (kudos to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794604/can-you-use-multiple-instances-of-edge-on-a-selenium-grid-node/40022571#40022571))
- the driver must be running in the foreground, so that the browser window can be actually displayed on the desktop. Therefore the node cannot be started as a Windows Service nor from Windows Task Scheduler at startup. The best way to automate starting of the node is to configure auto-login and add a batch script starting the node to user's Startup Programs as described in [my article](http://morgwai.pl/articles/selenium-edge.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the -D parameters before the -jar parameter. I had an issue where it thought -Dwebdriver..... was a parameter to selenium itself instead of java.

Comment: That little thing about no documentation explaining having the -D defined variables up front wasted a lot of time. Also make sure to single or doublequote paths if they contain spaces, and use absolute paths.