# Edge webdriver not navigating to page with remotedriver (C#)

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, selenium-edgedriver

I'm trying to use the Edge Driver for the first time but it is failing to navigate to a URL when using RemoteWebDriver. The browser opens but it stays on 'Blank page', generating the following error on the grid node.......

```
17:24:05.348 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, version=, platform=WINDOWS}]])
17:24:05.372 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, version=, platform=WINDOWS}]
[17:24:05.453] - Listening on http://localhost:24558/
17:24:06.020 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'SAL-36', ip: '192.168.0.12', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:36)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:190)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:222)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:184)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:150)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:543)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1228)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1130)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:112)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:122)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.ExecutingExecutionStrategy.invoke(ExecutingExecutionStrategy.java:58)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:201)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:133)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
```

It works fine when using the regular EdgeDriver instead of RemoteWebDriver.

This is my node file...

```
java -jar "C:\Selenium\Grid\selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar" -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=5 -browser browserName=chrome,platform=WIN10,maxInstances=5 -browser browserName="internet explorer",platform=WIN10,maxInstances=5 -browser browserName="MicrosoftEdge",platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=1 -port 5555
```

I have all my webdrivers in the same directory on my machine - `C:\Selenium\Webdrivers` and have an environment variable to the folder

I am using.....

- selenium 3.0.1 nuget package (RemoteWebDriver doesn't work in 3.4.0)
- Edge Driver Release 15063
- Edge version 40.15063.0.0
- OS version 15063.413

All other WebDrivers are currently working in selenium grid.

If anyone is able to help I would be eternally grateful

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45621125/1220560) having Edge in the same node with other browsers is known to cause such problems. The workaround is to start 2 separate nodes on the same machine: one only for Edge and second for IE, FF and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get one step further however the driver is far too flaky to be used in production. Even with edge on separate grid nodes the tests fail to run in parallel, returning 'Unable to parse remote response' when attempting to load the second session. Clicks on visible and clickable elements don't always work, returning 'Element obscured' (I have to use javascript for all my clicks) and file uploads via input sendkeys fail with 'The element is not focusable'. Everything is fine in Chrome and Firefox. If you've had any success with any/all of these issues let me know.

Comment: as explained [here](https://twitter.com/instylevii/status/783480823445987329) Edge driver can have only 1 session at a time: attempt to run more than 1 edge tests in parallel is expected to fail. If you limit 'maxInstances' for edge to 1 (as it is in the example from the link in my answer) and run it in a dedicated node then it's pretty stable.